# init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding

Tags: django, apache, apache2.4

I'm running Django website on apache.

Here is the tail of my `httpd.conf` file.

```
ServerName 127.0.0.1:8080


# Django Project
LoadFile "c:/python39/python39.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/python39/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp39-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/python39/"
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/pd_videowebapp/mysite/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "C:/pd_videowebapp/"

<Directory "C:/pd_videowebapp/mysite/">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static "C:/pd_videowebapp/static/"
<Directory "C:/pd_videowebapp/static/">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And here is the tail of the `error.log` file:

```
The 'Apache2.4' service is restarting.
Starting the 'Apache2.4' service
The 'Apache2.4' service is running.
pm_winnt:notice] [pid 4472:tid 420] AH00455: Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) mod_wsgi/4.9.0 Python/3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 13 08:31:28.026005 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4472:tid 420] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Oct  7 2021 16:27:02
[Wed Oct 13 08:31:28.026005 2021] [core:notice] [pid 4472:tid 420] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24'
[Wed Oct 13 08:31:28.041641 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4472:tid 420] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2676
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Python39'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Python39'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Python39'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Python39'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Python39\\python39.zip',
    '.\\DLLs',
    '.\\lib',
    'C:\\Apache24\\bin',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00001bd8 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
[Wed Oct 13 08:31:28.385413 2021] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 4472:tid 420] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
```

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @isifzade I installed Ubuntu in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Windows 10 users:

1. Press Windows logo on Toolbar.
2. Type and open `Edit the system environment variables`.
3. In `Advance` tab press `Environment Variables` button.
4. For `System variables` press `New` button.
5. `Variable name` will be PYTHONHOME and `Variable value` will the path where the `python.exe` is located (i.e. c:/users/administrator/anaconda3/envs/my_env_name). Then press `OK`.
6. Again for `System variables` press `New` button.
7. `Variable name` will be PYTHONPATH and `Variable value` will the path of `site-packages` folder (i.e. C:/Users/Administrator/anaconda3/envs/my_env_name/Lib/site-packages). Then press `OK`.

Comment: I accept this answer, because I can't test it now. The server runs already on Ubuntu.

Comment: This did work for me, but I didn't want to set my system wide variables to point to a specific conda environment. 
Instead, in the apache httpd.conf file, you can specify both variables using `WSGIPythonHome` and `WSGIPythonPath` with the same paths as describe in the answer.

Comment: Globally setting `PYTHONHOME` (or even `PYTHONPATH`, depending on what's there) is asking for trouble.  If you really need to set them, doing so in the specific place they're needed as suggested by @TimChild is the way to go.